# How can I change the color of the horizontal barcharts in EBM's visualization using explainer.visualize()?

Tags: python, plotly, plotly-dash

I am using Explainable Boosting Machines (EBM) for a classification problem parallel with Plotly Dash. In one of my callbacks I am trying to change the color of each feature when it is clicked.

The visualization looks like below:
[image: Visualization of EBM]

What I want is to highlight each bar when it is clicked.

The code that I'm using is like below:

```
@app.callback(
Output(component_id='ebm-plot', component_property='figure'),
[
    Input(component_id='ebm-plot', component_property='figure'),
    Input(component_id='ebm-plot', component_property='clickData')
],
[
    State('ebm-model-explainer', 'data')
]
)
def highlight_selected_feature_on_ebm_plot(fig, clickData, explainer_filename):
    # Load the explainer
    explainer = pickle.load(open(explainer_filename, "rb"))

    # Extract feature importance values and names
    feature_importance = explainer.data(0)['scores']
    feature_names = explainer.data(0)['names']

    # Convert fig from dict to plotly.graph_objects.Figure
    fig = go.Figure(fig)

    # Get the index of the clicked bar, if any
    clicked_index = clickData['points'][0]['pointIndex'] if clickData is not None else None

    # Define color for the overlay bar
    overlay_color = 'rgba(0,0,0)'  # semi-transparent black

    # Create an overlay bar for the clicked index
    if clicked_index is not None:
        fig.add_trace(
        go.Bar(
            x=[feature_importance[clicked_index]],
            y=[feature_names[clicked_index]],
            orientation='h',
            marker_color=overlay_color,
            hoverinfo='none',
            showlegend=False
        )
    )

return fig
```

What this function does is creating a mask on the real figure which is not working properly for me and causes the bars' order to change or the caption gets lost.

Is there a default feature for this in explainer.visualize()?

You can find more information in [this link](https://interpret.ml/docs/framework.html).

I want the result to be something like below:
[image: Highlighting of the selected feature in EBM visualization]

Comment: Hey, not sure you've seen the answer below and got the point, I made an edit to make things clearer, just in case.

Answer (score 0):

Plotly can do that out of the box (ie. without having to use a Dash callback). When (re)building the 'ebm-plot' figure, you just need to :

1. Set the marker [color of selected points](https://plotly.com/python/reference//bar/#bar-selected-marker-color) to black.
2. Set the [`clickmode`](https://plotly.com/python/reference/layout/#layout-clickmode) for single click interactions (with `event+select`, selection also accumulates (or un-accumulates) data if you hold down shift while clicking).

For example :

```py
fig = go.Figure(go.Bar(...))
fig.update_traces(selected_marker_color='rgba(0,0,0,1)') # (1)
fig.update_layout(clickmode='event+select')              # (2)

app.layout = html.Div([
    # ...
    dcc.Graph(id='ebm-plot', figure=fig)
    # ...
])
```

That's it, you can remove the `highlight_selected_feature_on_ebm_plot()` callback (if another callback is supposed to rebuild entirely the figure given some input, don't forget these 2 things).